# Store PHP array in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i'm still learning PHP, MySQL and a few other languages.
While i'm trying to improve and learn i have develpoed a browser game.

Now i'm trying to save a "battle log" from each fight that takes place, that will allow my users to go back and look at their past fights.

To solve this i have tried to store each fight round into a php array.
The problem for me now is to save that array into my database, for a user to request and have displayed to them.

I have tried to mess around with PHP's serialize and also with json_encode.
But i fail to get them stored in my DB as it will eighter give me a syntax error or a empty row.

Here a example to display what i am trying to achive!

```
$i = 1;
$battle_log = array();

while( $i <= 10)
{
     $battle_log[] = "Round ".$i."<br>";
     $i++;
}

foreach ($battle_log as $rounds => $round) {
    echo "".$round."";
}

$save_log = json_encode($battle_log);
$sql = "INSERT INTO battle_log_test VALUES fighter1_id='13', fighter2_id='45', battle_log='".$save_log."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

All input to help me solve this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: data type of battle_log ?

Comment: Data type should be `TEXT` for 'battle_log' in your table and I think you should try `json_encode($battle_log, true)`

Comment: Yeah, it's TEXT in my DB.

Comment: @hmd what is json_encode($battle_log, true) ? Documentation mentions the 'true' option for json_decode only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO battle_log (fighter1_id,fighter2_id,battle_log) VALUES (13,45,'".$save_log."');";
$sql = $mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die($mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: Tried this and it works like a charm! :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT query is wrong, should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO battle_log_test 
    (fighter1_id, fighter2_id, battle_log) 
VALUES 
    ('13', '45', '".$save_log."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP serialize() function insted json_encode()

```
$i = 1;
$battle_log = array();

while( $i <= 10)
{
 $battle_log[] = "Round ".$i."<br>";
 $i++;
}

foreach ($battle_log as $rounds => $round) {
    echo "".$round."";
}

$save_log = serialize($battle_log);
$sql = "INSERT INTO battle_log_test VALUES fighter1_id='13', fighter2_id='45', battle_log='".$save_log."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or  die(mysqli_error($connection));
```